# android Upload image to server

Tags: java, android

Hello guy I'm trying do upload the some image to Server using REST, but doesn't work.
Could you help ?

```
    private void uploadImage()
{
    String url ="http://192.168.54.2:8081/Cesario/titoy.php";

    String pasta = getPath(path);

    try
    {
        String upload_ID = UUID.randomUUID().toString().trim();

        new MultipartUploadRequest(this,upload_ID,url)
                .addFileToUpload(pasta,"imagem")
                .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                .setMaxRetries(3)
                .startUpload();

        alert.hide();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.v("vampiro",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Exception:

> 01-14 16:36:58.814 14633-14657/com.example.antnioncolau.jjjjjjj
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode, referenced
>   from method
>   net.gotev.uploadservice.http.impl.HurlStackConnection.setHeaders 01-14
>   16:36:58.814 14633-14657/com.example.antnioncolau.jjjjjjj W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22551:
>   Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;.setFixedLengthStreamingMode (J)V

Comment: Do you get some exception?

Comment: 01-14 16:36:58.814 14633-14657/com.example.antnioncolau.jjjjjjj I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.net.HttpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode, referenced from method net.gotev.uploadservice.http.impl.HurlStackConnection.setHeaders
01-14 16:36:58.814 14633-14657/com.example.antnioncolau.jjjjjjj W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 22551: Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;.setFixedLengthStreamingMode (J)V